# RPC C++ Dynamic Library

Tags: c++, rpc

I am student of M.Sc Computer Science. I have been given a project on C++ Analytics Library. I have been asked to implement some key analytics functions, design a library to implement these functions, and to make the library available via Remote Procedure Call interface.

I don't have programming background except what I learned about C++ during my course. I can do the coding for analytics function but I am stuck on RPC stuff? I could not find good resources on RPC or honestly if I say that I am not understanding from where to start on RPC? There are a lot of RPC information but could not relate to my project. I am supposed to design library for windows environment.

So far this is what I am planning to do-

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (Trial Edition)

Create IDL interface file where I am going to define all procedure or functions.
Using MIDL complier, generate client and server stub files.
and then link and compile the server and client using stub and header file.

Do you guys think that I am on right track for my project?
If yes, is there any help or best resource available for writing IDL interface file?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I am not looking for the code. I am looking for the help in regards to RPC.